# Spark partitions size on coalesce

Tags: java, apache-spark

*Is there any way to ask Spark to make partitions of equal size on `coalesce`?*

```
Stats[] stats = sparkSession
    .read()
    .parquet(salesPath)
    .coalesce(5) // may produce partitions of 120, 1, 1, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have equal size partitions with `coalesce`.
You should use `repartition` for that.

Check out https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations